# Cosa sono "gli occhi a sportello"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il fu Mattia Pascal*, di Luigi Pirandello, ho letto:

> — *Dôva ca l'è stô me car parent?* — si mise a gridare con stretto accento torinese, senza togliersi dal capo il cappelluccio dalle tese rialzate, calcato fin su gli **occhi a sportello**, appannati dal vino, né la pipetta dalla bocca, con cui pareva stesse a cuocersi il naso più rosso di quello della signorina Caporale.

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "occhi a sportello" in questo brano. Ho cercato nella voce "sportello" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato niente a riguardo. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In un Dizionario della lingua italiana dell'inizio dell'Ottocento, è riportato un esempio in cui gli occhi a sportello sono un modo (scherzoso) per descrivere "chi tiene gli occhi socchiusi, o vede da un occhio solo".

Da [Dizionario della lingua italiana](https://books.google.it/books?id=UjZAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA453&lpg=PA453&dq=occhi%20a%20sportello&source=bl&ots=Y8X2nQoNaA&sig=Sa_5LdxRQSaaH_q053-TeCXKQsk&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjB1Zr2mNHSAhVDShQKHSZaAZYQ6AEIUjAR#v=onepage&q=occhi%20a%20sportello&f=false), Volume 6,
di Paolo Costa, Francesco Cardinali.

Comment: @Charo: grazie!